# In c, what does this parameter means `myfunc(mystruct_t * const * pVar)`?

Tags: c, pointers, constants

Saw this `pVar` parameter definition in a demo program, does this means it is constant pointer value and constant pointer address?

```c
void myfunc(mystruct_t * const * pVar) 
{
   // ...
}
```

Comment: This is not valid C code, functions need to have return type specified. Having said, that, [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=struct+mystruct_t+*+const+*+pVar)

Comment: thanks for the sharp eye. updated. @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. just saw the given link, [cdecl.org](https://cdecl.org/) is simply awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that `pVar` is a (non-const) pointer to a const pointer to a (non-const) mystruct_t object.

General rule for reading and understanding C declarations -- start from the name (pVar here) and read out from there.  When there are both prefix and suffix things, the suffix things are higher precedence, so come first, unless there are parens to get the prefix things first.

Comment: thanks Chris, especially on how to read the variable. May I know how to declare a 'constant pVar pointer to constant pointer to a (non-const) mystruct_t` object?

Comment: That would be `mystruct_t * const * const pVar`

Comment: thanks, that's clear all the doubt!